# WPF: override button's IsEnabled evaluation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom class deriving from Button.
Basically it provides different interactions (e.g. long press), whereas the regular button only has a single command for when it's being released.

What I want to do now is disable the button if no interaction is possible and enable it if any is.
I have a corresponding bool AnyCommandExecutable and if I use this for styling (e.g. coloring my button when it is not interactive) it works just fine.

But if I try (in xaml)

```
<MyButton IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=AnyCommandExecutable, Mode=OneWay}"...
```

WPF simply ignores this binding and disables my button, if the "Command" property is not executable (which is the default behaviour of the regular button).

I've also tried (in c#)

```
void EvaluateCommands()
{
    AnyCommandExecutable = ...;
    IsEnabled = AnyCommandExecutable;
}
```

resulting again in WPF ignoring my assignement to IsEnabled.

Comment: I gather you have a command you're binding or providing somehow. Which could use canexecute. Can't you provide your logic in canexecute for your button's command?

Comment: I do have multiple commands, each containing separate CanExecute logic.
Still WPF controls my buttons IsEnabled flag solely based on the command called "Command" (which is the default buttons on click command).

Comment: And this command will have canexecute.

Comment: Yes. My logic basically is:
AnyCommandExecutable = (Command != null && Command.CanExecute(...))
                                         || (LongPressCommand != null && LongPressCommand.CanExecute(...))

Comment: I think you're missing my point, which is: make that canexecute fix your problem.

Comment: @Andy: This is indeed a possible workaround. Thank you! But if possible I would like to have a proper solution, since forcing the Command's CanExecute method to use my logic will break, if a somebody else (a colleague) sets the Command in xaml (since this overrides my logic).

Comment: You could override the isenabled dependency property. Provide a coerce callback that extracts the two commands, checks their canexecute values and sets isenabled accordingly.